# Is there a difference between "DHE_PSK" and "PSK_DHE"?

Tags: tls

While studying the [list of available TLS cipher suites](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml), I noticed the following two:

- TLS_**DHE_PSK**_WITH_AES_128_CCM
- TLS_**PSK_DHE**_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8

They are defined in RFC 6655, [Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6655#section-4).

Is there any reason why the "**DHE**" and "**PSK**" parts are switched around? Does this only have legacy/compatibility reasons or are there actual technical differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a mistake. See [Errata 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=6655&eid=3987) for this RFC:

> Section 4 says:
>
> ```
>          CipherSuite TLS_PSK_DHE_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 = {0xC0,0xAA}
>          CipherSuite TLS_PSK_DHE_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8 = {0xC0,0xAB}
> ```
>
> It should say:
>
> ```
>          CipherSuite TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 = {0xC0,0xAA}
>          CipherSuite TLS_DHE_PSK_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8 = {0xC0,0xAB}
> ```